# relay cache invalidation using pattern queries

Tags: graphql, relayjs

I'm using relay for a react-native app and need to force invalidate, or forceFetch my a query at certain points in the app's lifecycle. I've noticed that you can create a query using Relay and then forceFetch it. This updates the cache. Ideally, I'd like to do what is done in the Mutations API. I'd like to provide a fat query that intersects with my existing data, and refetches that intersection. But I can't figure out how to do this. If I attempt to do this:

```
 var query = Relay.createQuery(
    Relay.QL`
      query Root {
        viewer {
          unreadNotificationCount,
          notifications
        }
      }
   `, {

   }
```

And apply `environment.forceFetch({ query })`I get validation errors about `notifications` not including either `first` or `last` arguments. But I'd rather not have to include first, or last arguments, because I don't know how many notifications have loaded in the rest of my app.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no trivial way for you to do that intersection, at least not just using `forceFetch`. The mutation API does much more than try to just fetch a pattern query - it performs the intersection against the local graph to compute the actual mutation query that is sent.

You can definitely ask an individual container to refetch it's date using [forceFetch](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-container.html#forcefetch), though. So if you have a container that fetches the notifications (I suspect you do), simply trigger `forceFetch` on it every N seconds.